# Does h1:before{ } work for seo?

Tags: html, css, seo

Would `<h1></h1>` and `h1:before{ content: "title";}` work the same as `<h1>title</h1>`?

I am creating a responsive page with my name at the top as a title between h1 tags e.g *"John Smith"* but it does not fit in with the navigation when on a mobile browser so i would like it to just say *"John"* on a mbile browser. I can achieve this with a media query in my css using `:before` to set the content based on the viewport size.

I just need to know if it would validate as "John Smith" between the h1 tags for SEO reasons?

Comment: content:''; add text or image that  exist only if CSS is run , so you can expect that it will not be visible for search engines. Even for javascript it is not easy cause it doesn't exist in the DOM

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO which is off-topic at Stack Overflow.


Comment: @JohnConde I'm not so sure, the question does involve code...

Comment: well my question was answered, so i don't see a problem. it is a very valid question that is very helpful in context with coding a page/site or program. It says nowhere in the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page that this type of question is unallowed as it is directly related to programming. I think your comment is very nonconstructive and you could spend your time answering peoples questions you know something about rather than complaining about peoples questions you are unable to answer whereas clearly experienced and helpful people who answered the question were able to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about the impact of the `:after` and `:before` on SEO. It is however content that you are placing in your stylesheet when you use this method, and I think that shoudl be considered bad practice. I would solve more like this:

HTML:

```
<h1>John <span class='hide-mobile'>Smith</span></h1>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .hide-mobile {
     display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly if the mobile version does not add characters to the title (e.g. replacing a long word by a short one)

Comment: simple and brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

Choose one as the title that should be used in a page outline, preferably the large one. Then add mobile gimmicks.

```
<h1 class="suppressed-on-mobile">John Smith</h1>
<div class="mobile-heading">John</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mobile-heading {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .suppressed-on-mobile {
    display: none;
  }

  .mobile-heading {
    display: block;
    font-size: 150%;
    /* etc... */
  }
}
```

That way, text browsers, search engines, screen readers etc. know what to display.

Search engines do not parse the `content` property, so you should not have actual content in CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

For mobile via `mediaqueries` , you could set a hudge `word-spacing` , `white:space:nowrap;` and `overflow:hidden` on `<h1>` to  send off screen  those extra words bothering you :).

Comment: no need to modify markup.